# Airflow - Questions on batch jobs and running a task in a DagRun multiple times

Tags: airflow

I am trying to solve the following problem with airflow:

I have a data pipeline where I want to run several processes on a number of excel documents (eg: 5,000 excel files a day). My idea for a DAG is below:

Task 1 = Take an excel file, and adds a new sheet to it.

Task 2 =  Convert this returned excel to a PDF.

Task 1 and 2 in the DAG would call a processing tool running outside airflow via an API call (So the actual data processing isnt happening inside airflow).

I seem to be going around in circles with figuring out the best approach to this workflow. Some questions I keep having are:

- Should each DagRun be one excel, or should the DagRun take in a batch
  of excels?
- If taking in a batch (which I presume is the correct approach), what is the recommend batch amount?
- How would I pass the returned values from task 1 to task 2. Would it be an XCOM dictionary with a reference to each newly saved excel? I read somewhere that the max size of an xcom should be 48kb. So if i have a XCOM of 5,000 excel filepaths, that will probabaly be larger than 48kb.
- The last, most tricky question I have is, I would obviously want to start processing task 2 as soon as even 1 excel from Task 1 had completed, because i wouldnt want to wait for the entire batch of Task 1 to complete before starting Task 2. How can I run Task 2, multiple times within the same DagRun for each new result that Task 1 produces? Or should Task 2 be its own DAG?

Am I approaching this problem the right way? How should I be tackling this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumptions

I made some assumptions since I don't know all the details of the Excel file processing:

1. You cannot merge the Excel files since you need them separate.
2. Excel files are accessible from Airflow DAG (same filesystem or similar).

If something of that is not true, please clarify accordingly.

### Answers

That being said, I'll first answer your questions and then comment on some thoughts:

1. I think you can do in batches, since using one run per file will be very slow (because of the scheduler time mostly, that will add time between Excel files processing). You're also not using all the available resources, so better push Airflow to be more busy.
2. The batch amount will depend on the processing load and the task design. From your question I assume you're thinking about having the batch inside the task, but if the service that process the Excel files could handle good parallelism, I'd rather recommend one task per Excel file. Having 5000 tasks (one for each file) will be a bad idea (because that'll be difficult so see in the UI), but the exact number of processes per batch depends on your resources and service SLA mostly.
3. From my experience I recommend using one task for everything, since you can call the service in parallel and right after the service completes, you can directly transform the Excel file in PDF.
4. This gets solved with the answer from question #3.

### Solution overview

The solution I imagine is something like:

- First task for checking existence of pending files. You can do a fork using a [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html?highlight=branch#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator) (example [here](https://registry.astronomer.io/dags/example-branch-operator)).
- Then you have X parallel tasks to process Excel (call the service) and transform that to PDF. Could be one `PythonOperator` task. If you use Airflow 2, you can simply use [`@task()` decorator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html#tasks) to simplify the code. The `X` could be from 10 to 100 for example, depending on the resources and the service throughput.
- Have a final task that triggers the DAG again to process more files. This could be implemented using a [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html?highlight=trigger%20dag#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator) (example [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/trigger-dag-operator)).